# jspdf cannot generate pdf in mobile (android/ iPhone)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jspdf

can we generate pdf using jspdf in mobile phones and tabs?
I have simple android application (no Phonegap no Cordova), and an IOS application, jspdf works in web smoothly , but not able to generate pdf in IOS and Android.

```
doc.output('save', 'Pass.pdf');
```

works fine for web-browsers.
I tried

```
doc.save();
```

and

```
 var blob = pdf.output();
 window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

and when I tried :

```
 var res = doc.output(); 
 var blob = new Blob([res]);
 window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

I received somthing like this in the android

```
onLoadResource=data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1OTUuMjggODQxLjg5XQovQ29udGVudHM......
```

but no pdf

so Now I want to know , is it even possible to generate pdf in mobiles using **jspdf**?or is it all in vain?

If yes , how?

Answer (score 1):

**IOS:**
**Google told me that**:
To download PDFs to your iPad, iPhone, or iPod Touch, you'll need to download an application.

Hence it wasn't possible to do it from jspdf directly so I quit trying onto that.

**Android:**
I din't find any solution regarding that, I moved to another solution.

**Image instead of PDF** (for both iPhone and Android)

The Information which you want to show in pdf, base64 that information , and send it to Android Api , which could convert it to png and save it to photo gallery.

I hope this may help somebody in future.